# Text with the same proportions as the graphic

Tags: graphics

What do I need to do to make the text keep the same proportions as the rectangle even when I increase the image size?

```
altura=180;largura=250;
g=Graphics[{White,EdgeForm[Thickness[0.01]],Rectangle[{0,0},{largura,altura}],Black,Text[Style["TC-01",100],{largura/2,altura/2}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Lcarvalho, can you pls check if [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/208269/125) answers your question?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FontSize -> Scaled[s]` in `Style` to get **a font whose point size is a fraction *s* of the horizontal plot range.**

```
Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Thickness[0.01]], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {largura, altura}], Black, 
   Text[Style["TC-01", FontSize -> Scaled[.3]], {largura/2, altura/2}]}, 
  ImageSize -> #] & /@ {50, 100, 300, 500} // Row
```

[image]

```
frames = Panel[Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[Thickness[0.01]], 
     Rectangle[{0, 0}, {largura, altura}], Black, 
     Text[Style["TC-01", FontSize -> Scaled[.3]], {largura/2, altura/2}]}, 
     ImageSize -> #], Style[#, 16] &@ToString[ImageSize -> #, StandardForm], 
     ImageSize -> {400, 300}, Alignment -> Center] & /@ 
   Range[30, 300, 10];

ListAnimate[frames, Alignment -> Center, 
 AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward, Paneled -> False]
```

[image]